# Changed files always showing in main branch

Tags: git, github

Does anyone know what causes this? I've pushed some files to my branch. It has no conflicts whatsoever, so my senior have merged it with the main branch, but whenever I switch to the main branch to fetch origin to get the latest update, the files that I've worked before previously always show up in the main as changed files but with "deleted" mark on it. Also, the files keep returning whenever I discard the changes, switch to my branch, and switch it back to main.

I'm using Github desktop.

Comment: There is no such thing as "push files" or push "to a branch". Please state in clear Git terms what you really did.

Comment: It would help if you post here the exact git commands you run and what happens in between them (e.g. you change something, you colleague pushes or merges etc). And where you would expect things to be different than what you see.

Comment: @matt my senior set up two branches, the main branch and a branch with my name on it, I worked on some files, commit, and pushed them to my branch. If there's no conflict, then my senior merged my branch into the main. the problem is exactly what was described above.

Comment: @Gec https://ibb.co/nk0zy8F the problem is exactly in this screen snap, whenever I want to pull some new changes from the main branch to my branch, I had to switch branch, and there's that changed files with deleted icon on it, when in fact those files exist in the remote repository and not deleted

Comment: "whenever I want to pull some new changes from the main branch to my branch, I had to switch branch" That is not true. You do _not_ need to change branches in order to update locally. In fact, you do not need a local main branch at all. Stay on "the branch with my name on it".

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just misunderstanding the GUI display. It's confusing.  (That is one reason why I never use a GUI on Git.) It sounds like a matter of interpreting a diff. If your local main branch did not have these files, and you fetch the remote origin/main which *does* have these files, then it is perfectly true that with respect to origin/main, your local main branch is "missing" the files, which is what your GUI portrays as "deleted".